# In d3js, how do I draw customized shape (<path>) on this globe instead of circle?

Tags: d3.js

I found a d3 globe here: http://bl.ocks.org/PatrickStotz/1f19b3e4cb848100ffd7

Update:

Thanks to @Lary Ciminera 's answer the pin is now on the globe, but it's not in the correct location. For instance, in this case, I want the pin to be at New York (in the center, where I put a pin manually) but it's on the left and upper place.

[image: Globe]

The cities were marked as points by this code:

```
path.pointRadius(function(d) {
   return d.properties ? rScale(d.properties.population) : 1;

});

// Drawing transparent circle markers for cities
g.selectAll("path.cities").data(data.features)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class", "cities")
   .attr("d", path)
   .attr("fill", "#ffba00")
   .attr("fill-opacity", 0.3);
```

However, I want to use a svg graph to replace the circle, for example, a pin that I defined in my own path code:

```
<path d="M217.087,119.397c-24.813,0-45,20.187-45,45s20.187,45,45,45s45-20.187,45-45S241.901,119.397,217.087,119.397z"/>
<path d="M217.087,0c-91.874,0-166.62,74.745-166.62,166.619c0,38.93,13.421,74.781,35.878,103.177l130.742,164.378l130.742-164.378
  c22.457-28.396,35.878-64.247,35.878-103.177C383.707,74.745,308.961,0,217.087,0z M217.087,239.397c-41.355,0-75-33.645-75-75
  s33.645-75,75-75s75,33.645,75,75S258.443,239.397,217.087,239.397z"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It use geometries from imported geojson `"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[lat ,long]}`

What you can do,instead to make 'path' genreate path drop geometry, is to draw your path for each value and move this path to the correct coordinate

```
  g.selectAll("path.cities").data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "cities")
        .attr('d',"M217.087,0c...43,239.397,217.087,239.397z") // drawn your path
        .attr('transform', d => {
           //here you move it to the correct position (scale is because your path is too big
           return `translate(${projection(d.geometry.coordinates)}) scale(0.1)`;
         })
        .attr("fill", "#ffba00");
```

Comment: ( you can concatanate both your path for the  "M217.087,119.397c-24.813,0-45,20.187-45,45s20.187,45,45,45s45-20.187,45-45S241.901,119.397,217.087,119.397zM217.087,0c-91.874,0-166.62,74.745-166.62,166.619c0,38.93,13.421,74.781,35.878,103.177l130.742,164.378l130.742-164.378
  c22.457-28.396,35.878-64.247,35.878-103.177C383.707,74.745,308.961,0,217.087,0z M217.087,239.397c-41.355,0-75-33.645-75-75
  s33.645-75,75-75s75,33.645,75,75S258.443,239.397,217.087,239.397z") so you don't have to create 2 paths

Comment: Thanks, Lary, it's showed, but not on the correct location. It seems the `translate(x,y)` should be adjusted. Is there any extra work I need to do to the x and y?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot to demonstrate the problem I encountered.

Comment: Another problem is that the pin doesn't follow the rotating as the circle would. The pin would just be there.

Comment: for the rotation to work you have to update transform transition in 
`function spinning_globe(){...}` instead of just setting new path? for the pin to be at the correct potition you can change your path so that the showed location of the pin is 0,0.

Comment: Or you can put the path inside a <g> with the correct ajustement.

Comment: also i fear that you have no way of telling if your image correspond to the d3.projection, since your image seems to be static, and the projection start centered on europe if im not mistaking.

Comment: Thanks, Lary, how do I make this SVG graph correspond to the d3.projection?

Comment: instead of using an image you can draw the world map using projection.I think you can find anything you need in this post : https://observablehq.com/@figurescc/stadiums-around-the-world-step-by-step